# Can you identify a colored line in a html5 canvas build from an image of a chart?

Tags: html, canvas, colors, charts

Let's say I have an image of a line graph, pretty simple, probably a white background, black axis lines, and some other color for the line.  I am going to turn the image into canvas and I would like to know if there is a way to identify that line with canvas.  This would allow me to do a lot of things, like manipulate the line, etc...

Answer (score 2):

You can identify colors by using `getImageData` but there are definitely drawbacks using that method with what you want to do.

Heres an example of doing what your talking about

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/KbUxY/)**

```
// get the line
var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height),
    points = [];

for(var y=0; y<canvas.height; y++){
    for(var x=0; x<canvas.width; x++){
       if(imageData.data[(y * (canvas.height*4) + (x*4))+2] == 255){ 
          points[x] = y;
       }
    }
}

// redraw the line with a y offset
ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(255,0,0)";
ctx.beginPath();
for(var i = 0; i < points.length; i++){
    ctx.lineTo(i, points[i]+20);   
}
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();
```

What the above does is gather all the points that have a blue threshold of 255. But if any lines intersect, etc, this would be thrown off because the pixel value would be different.

Comment: Thanks for this, it helps.  But, I am not drawing the line graph image, it is just any image of a line graph.

Comment: @iweczek I just plotted some points as an example, that would work on an image as well, but the caution about color bleed is still valid. If I get time today Ill make a demo with an image and a threshold unless someone beats me to it.

Comment: thanks man. ideally, a mouse click would identify the pixel and color of the line in the image.  I know this makes it more complicated but that would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its not very hard to do that, you simply have to keep track of everything you draw yourself so you can redraw it (by clearing the canvas and drawing everything again with possibly new coordinates).

I have a [simple tutorial](http://simonsarris.com/blog/510-making-html5-canvas-useful) on how to make objects (in this case rectangles) that you keep track of so you can redraw them (the tutorial covers dragging). All of the principles could apply to lines, or anything else for that matter.

On a side note, doing something simple like this is much easier in SVG where a lot of the stuff (retained drawing that you can change the coordinates of on the fly, mouse events, etc) is already done for you. You might want to consider using SVG instead.

Comment: I am not drawing the intial line graph image, it is just any image of any line graph.

Comment: Sorry, then you want something closer to Loktar's answer. I'd really question why you want to do this with images though, you might be looking for the right solution to solving the wrong problem, so to speak

Answer (score 0):

First you draw the image to a canvas element with drawImage(), and then get the pixel data from the canvas.

```
var canvas = $("#yourCanvas"); 
var context = canvas.get(0).getContext("2d"); 

var image = new Image(); 
image.src = "imagename.jpg"; 
var imageData; 
var pixels; 

$(image).load(function() { 

    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0); 
    imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, image.width, image.height); 
    pixels = imageData.data; // pixel data array of width*height*4 elements
                             // (r,g,b,alpha for every pixel)

});  

context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width(), canvas.height());
```

Now you could walk into the pixels array to check for the color value by doing something like this.

```
var pos = 0; // index position into pixels array

for (y = 0; y < image.height; y++) {
    for (x = 0; x < image.width; x++) {

        var red = pixels[pos++]; 
        var green = pixels[pos++]; 
        var blue = pixels[pos++]; 
        var alpha = pixels[pos++];


        /* if is not black (red!=0, green!=0 and blue!=0) nor white (red!=255, 
           green!=255, blue!=255) it's the line are you looking for
           so use context.lineTo(x,y); and start drawing the first point.. and so on */


    }
}
```

Keep in mind that I am considering perfect 0,0,0 black and perfect 255,255,255 white. maybe you should implement some noise reduction to handle real life applications.